# How to hide bottom bar(displaying 3 menu option) in android 4.0 using tablet

Tags: android, android-widget, uinavigationbar

I want to hide the bottom bar of my testing device for my whole application permanently.
I checked a lot of portals and sites but don't get the require result. so please help me.

Comment: This is a system-wide and system-side setting, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

If by bottom bar you mean the bar with the home, back and recent apps buttons you can't do this. That bar is designed to be omnipresent and can't be removed permanently. You can hide it temporarily, but the first touch will bring it back.

Comment: Thanks Dude. So it's mean this is not possible. Can you guide me to do it for temporarily. Thanks in advance..